# TypeError: queue.Queue is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning redis with Node.js to implement the Queue system

with file "producer_worker.js"

```
// producer_worker.js
var redis = require("redis")
var client = redis.createClient();
var queue = require("./queue");
var logsQueue = new queue.Queue("logs", client);
var MAX = 5;
for (var i = 0;i < MAX; i++) {
    logsQueue.push("Hello world #" + i);
}
console.log("Created " + MAX + " logs");
client.quit();
```

and "queue.js"

```
function Queue(queueName, redisClient) {
    this.queueName = queueName;
    this.redisClient = redisClient;
    this.queueKey = "queues:" + queueName;
    this.timeout = 0;

    Queue.prototype.size = function (callback) {
        this.redisClient.llen(this.queueKey, callback);
    };
    Queue.prototype.push = function(data) {
        this.redisClient.lpush(this.queueKey, data);
    };
    Queue.prototype.pop = function(callback) {
        this.redisClient.brpop(this.queueKey, this.timeout, callback);
    };
    exports.Queue = Queue;  
}
```

It generates error when I tried to run it :

```
node producer_worker.js 
var logsQueue = new queue.Queue("logs", client)
TypeError: queue.Queue is not a constructor
```

I have checked multiple times to ensure my codes consistent with those of book.

How could I fix the TypeError?

Comment: exports.Queue = Queue;  can't be in function scope

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're exporting `Queue` when executing it. So it obviously hasn't yet been exported when you call `require('./queue')`. So in order to fix this, you need to export `Queue` on runtime instead.

```
function Queue(queueName, redisClient) {
    this.queueName = queueName;
    this.redisClient = redisClient;
    this.queueKey = "queues:" + queueName;
    this.timeout = 0;
}

Queue.prototype.size = function (callback) {
    this.redisClient.llen(this.queueKey, callback);
};
Queue.prototype.push = function(data) {
    this.redisClient.lpush(this.queueKey, data);
};
Queue.prototype.pop = function(callback) {
    this.redisClient.brpop(this.queueKey, this.timeout, callback);
};
module.exports = Queue;  

// Usage
var Queue = require("./queue");
var logsQueue = new Queue("logs", client);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pull off some of your code from function scope:

```js
function Queue(queueName, redisClient) {
    this.queueName = queueName;
    this.redisClient = redisClient;
    this.queueKey = "queues:" + queueName;
    this.timeout = 0;
}

Queue.prototype.size = function (callback) {
    this.redisClient.llen(this.queueKey, callback);
};
Queue.prototype.push = function(data) {
    this.redisClient.lpush(this.queueKey, data);
};
Queue.prototype.pop = function(callback) {
    this.redisClient.brpop(this.queueKey, this.timeout, callback);
};
module.exports = { Queue: Queue };
```